# If memtest says "Boot error", is it fatal?

Tags: linux, boot, memtest86+

I have an old Pentium 4 1.5Gz machine with 512MB of RAM (from around 2001) that I used as a Linux server/seedbox/playbox.

It started having a problem mounting the root partition. I tried re-installing my distro of choice and it paused. My HDD passed the WD (it's a WD HDD) thorough test so I disconnected all PCI cards (except VGA), the HDD, and the CDROMs, and used a memtest (www.memtest86.com) floppy.

It didn't even boot. It just printed the message `Boot error` and halted there. I tested the floppy on my desktop (and a VM) and it works okay.

I'm just ready to send the mobo, RAM, CPU, and the legacy PCI cards to the recycle, but just before I do it, I want to make sure that it's not something that can be fixed.

What does that sound like?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is not reading the media where Memtest resides.  This could be a BIOS or hard drive (floppy ?  In 2015 thats a novelty, and probably the cause of the issue !   Showing my age here, I remember manually realigning floppy drives with no exotic tools or hardware - it could well be the head is out of alignment )

Why not try booting a USB key with Memtest etc - Many Linux distros have it, and there are even a number of performance/stress testing distros - [StressLinux](http://www.stresslinux.org/) was the first to pop up, but there are no doubt plenty of others.

That said, its probably not worth the effort rescusitating it except as a learning excersize of some sort - even an extremely low end new machine will outperform a P4, and, if it gets any significant use, will pay for itself in power savings alone.

Comment: I tried booting Linux from the DVDROM and CDRec and they both failed (Win98SE installed succesfully though!). This mobo doesn't boot from USB. So I had to go with the floppy. I also tried a floppy that would load a basic USB driver so I can boot from a stick but that floppy failed too (it worked on my desktop). The MSDOS floppy can boot okay.